# Não carregar um CSS caso seja IE8

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Problema:
Gostaria de não carregar o CSS caso seja o IE8

Para todos os outros browser desejo carregar o CSS

Pensei em fazer

```
<!--[if IE 8]> (deixar vazio)
```

e colocar para cada tipo de browser o CSS
Webkit, Gecko, mas acho que não é a solução

Existe algo do tipo? **ELSE?**

```
<!--[if IE]>

<![else]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe `ELSE` em comentários condicionais pelo que eu sei... mas é possível fazer um **NOT**:

```
<![if !(IE 8)]>
... IE 8 vai ignorar este bloco, mas os outros navegadores vão aceitá-lo
... estilo aqui ...
<![endif]>
```

Existem dois tipos de comentários condicionais no IE:

- **não revelados** (outros browsers não conseguem ver):

  ```
  <!--[if IE 8]>
  <p>Somente IE 8 vai var isso.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if !(IE 8)]>
  <p>IE diferente de 8 vai ver isso. Outros browsers não vão ver.</p>
  <![endif]-->
  ```
- **revelados** (outros browsers conseguem ver):

  ```
  <![if IE 8]>
  <p>Se for IE somente o 8 vai var isso, além dos outros browsers também verem.</p>
  <![endif]>

  <![if !(IE 8)]>
  <p>Se for IE e diferente de 8 vai ver isso. Outros browsers também vão ver.</p>
  <![endif]>
  ```

[Documentação sobre comentários condicionais](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed)<sup>(em Inglês)</sup>

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia. Só gostaria de fazer um adendo: comentários condicionais não são mais suportados a partir da versão 10 do IE. Caso haja problemas com isso, você pode simular o comportamento do IE 9 usando `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

Comment: @Carlos Boa observação. Valeu! Só pra dar suporte ao que disse: [Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Versão em português: [Comentários condicionais não têm mais suporte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o jeito de fazer isso seria criando uma folha de estilos que cancele os valores definidos e incluir no if IE. Por exemplo:

```
<style>
 #elemento{
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
}
</style>

<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
 #elemento{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
</style>
<[endif]-->
```

Comment: não dá..o CSS é extremamente complexo e grande..